# Prevent Ember from appending to the end of my RESTAdapter url?

Tags: ember.js

I'm using an API that doesn't have any `/post` or anything at the end.

But Ember automatically adds things to the end of my url. Here is the code:

```
    App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
        revision: 12,
        adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
            url: 'http://api.my-api.com/v1/products(name=my-name)&show=sku,name&Key=mYaPiKeY123'
        })
    });

    App.Offer = DS.Model.extend({
        name: DS.attr('string'),
        sku: DS.attr('string')
    });

    App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function () {
            return App.Offer.find();
        }
    });
```

Ember adds `/offers` to the end of the `url` and of course I get a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adapter's URL is specifically for the base URL of your API, e.g. `http://api.my-api.com/v1/`.  All the resource endpoint URLs are to be inferred from the model that you're requesting.  For instance, when using `App.Offer.find()`, it infers from the RESTAdapter's assumed convention that the resource is at `http://api.my-api.com/v1/offers`.  If you need to build custom URLs and/or you don't have control over the API's URL scheme, you can create your own RESTAdapter (or just a regular adapter) to handle the custom URLs.

If you want Ember Data to use query parameters when requesting resources, just use something like `this.store.findQuery('offer', {show: 'sku,name', another: 'parameter'});` and it will escape/serialize them into your URL automatically.

On another subject, it's not a great idea to include your API keys in your URL, as they're very vulnerable to exposure :-)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! But what about the (name=my-name) part of the url? Does anything special need to be done there since it's in parenthesis?

Comment: I get an error. Should I make a new issue for this? It's "Error while processing route: index undefined is not a function (evaluating App.Product.findQuery({show: 'sku,name', format: 'json', apiKey: 'MyApIkEy123'}))"

Comment: I've make a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27611053/error-evaluating-app-product-findquery

Comment: Updated the answer, should be `this.store.findQuery('offer'...` instead of `App.Offer.findQuery(...`

Comment: As for the `(name=my-name)`, what is it/what does it do?  I really don't think any API I've ever seen has supported something like that.  If it's static, then you can just put it in the `RESTAdapter`'s URL, but if it's dynamic, then you're going to have to extend the `RESTAdapter` to make it do what you want.  If the API is your own, however, I would say that you should remove that in favor of query parameters.

Comment: The `(name=my-name)` sets search values. So `(name=shakira)` returns stuff named `shakira`. And yes, the API key is in the URL too. Not my design. Also, it looks like `...findQuery('offer'...` part adds `/offer?` to the request, which breaks it. I tried setting that parameter to `false`, `NULL` and `''`, but no joy. (`''` pluralizes it to `s`).

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't look like `http://api.my-api.com/v1/products?name=my-name&show=sku,name&Key=mYaPiKeY123`?  That would make a lot more sense. If so, you can specify the `name` attribute in the query hash.

Comment: And to reiterate, `products` should not be in the URL you provide to the `RESTAdapter`.  That's inferred from the type of the model you're requesting.