# Error evaluating App.Product.findQuery

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to get data from an API like this:

```
    App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
        revision: 12,
        adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
            host: 'http://api.my-api/v1/products(name=my-name)'
        })
    });

    App.Product = DS.Model.extend({
        name: DS.attr('string')
    });

    App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function () {
            return App.Product.findQuery({show: 'sku,name', format: 'json', apiKey: 'MyApIkEy123'});
        }
    });
```

The error I get in the console is:

`Error while processing route: index undefined is not a function (evaluating 'App.Product.findQuery({show: 'sku,name', format: 'json', apiKey: 'MyApIkEy123'})')`

The JSON should look like this:

```
    {
        "from": 1,
        "to": 10,
        "total": 10,
        "products": [
            {
                "sku": 1234567,
                "name": "Great Product"
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are several problems on your post.

The first one is that you do not run `App.Product.findQuery` in your route but a `this.store.find(yoursamequery)` as `App.Product` extends `DS.Model` and `DS.Model` dosen't have `findQuery` method (thus you get undefined is not a function :)) 
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html

I think that your "format" and "apiKey" are not data filter but request parameters which have to be passed to your backend api right ? If so you should create an applicationAdapter with those parameters defined as in the documentation example :

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html

Comment: If they don't go in the header, do they still go in the applicationAdapter. Cause the API documentation says this is all in the URL. :/

Comment: You could explore on the build url methods then :) http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_buildURL with `var tmpUrl=this._super()` and then add your params to `tmpUrl` for example ...

Comment: Do you have some examples of `buildUrl` for a beginner?

Comment: I gave a try with a basic untested example : http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lobawicuzi/1/edit?html,js,output about the format of the returned JSON, you will have to customize it. the data recived have to be compilent to the jsonapi standard http://jsonapi.org/ used by ember

Comment: You can specify headers when you define the adapter, see http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#toc_headers-customization for details.

Answer (score 1):

In the model hook, try using:

`return this.store.findQuery('product', {show: 'sku,name', format: 'json', apiKey: 'MyApIkEy123'});`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to get your API to provide attributes that aren't in your model (i.e. sku, salePrice). Is that right? What does the response to that API call look like? If Ember Data is trying to set those attributes in your model object and not finding them, this could be the issue.

Comment: I've added the JSON format. But I'm not sure the request is even being made. I don't see it in Timeline in Web Inspector in Safari.

Comment: It looks like the salePrice isn't there, but that might be irrelevant. If it's not calling the API I'd suspect you might have the adapter set up wrong. Perhaps try pulling that out into it's own class, and then stepping through the code where you are setting the model hook.

Comment: Never mind, I upvoted what I think is the right answer.